# How to get resource id from String in Android

Tags: android

I need get a `resource ID` from `string`

```
String s = "R.raw.button5";

final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,Integer.valueOf((s));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code**, if you haven't tried anything then we cant help much. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getIdentifier(....). If you have button with id "R.id.button5" then this is your code.

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button5", "id", context.getPackageName());
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the resource id from resource name with [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> getIdentifier
>
> int getIdentifier (String name,
>                     String defType,
>                   String defPackage)
>
> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully
>   qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first
>   two components (package and type) are optional if defType and
>   defPackage, respectively, are specified here.
>
> **Note: use of this function is discouraged.** It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

To get the resource raw id, you can use something like:

```
Context context = getContext(); // base context or application context
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("button5", "raw", 
                                  context.getPackageName());

// Or
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/button5", null,
                                  context.getPackageName());
```

But you need to remember, as the note in documentation says, you better using the pregenerated resource id instead of getting from the resource name. It's because `getIdentifier()` need time to found the matching resource name as in the following code (from [Resources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#1722)):

```
public int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("name is null");
    }
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }
    return mAssets.getResourceIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage);
}
```

The other reason is, hard coding a resource name with `R.raw.button5` is a maintenance nightmare. Because there's a probability that you will change the name in the future, then you end up with a resource name pointing to nowhere.